# context not rendering im the html page - django

Tags: python, django

So the view is :

```
def username(request):
context = {}
if request.POST:
    pass
else:
    context['title'] = 'type a username'
    return render(request, 'update/one-input.html', context)
```

then in the html page :

```
<h5>{{ title }}</h5>
```

when i run the page its give me no error and its not showing any think inside the heading
i do the same code in another view in page and its work , why in this view not working 
so what is the problem ? ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assign it to `title` variable

```
def username(request):

    if request.POST:
        pass
    else:
        title = 'type a username'
        return render(request, 'update/one-input.html', {'title':title})
```

In html File. just use that variable.

```
<h5>{{ title }}</h5>
```

Key of the dictionary are used to access value in Jinja template.

Comment: nah its the same problem the content is not showing

Comment: can you provide the full code? It would be easier to debug.

Comment: @Msly try checking by using print statement that your code is even reaching else clock or not .

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your last line to this :

```
return render(request, 'update/one-input.html', {'context': context})
```

then in your `html` you will have `context` and all its content.

Comment: i have tried this before its the same thing is show me no thing the inner html is empty

Comment: @Msly you should call the name of context in this case it is ```context```. Something like this  ```<h1>{{ context }}</h1>```